# How to add column in dataframe one using another dataframe having one matching column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested-for-loop

```
Df1

|S.No Name     Area         Locality       Mobile_No |
|----------------------------------------------------|
|1    Sam      Canacona     Agonda         9456789034|
|2    Rose     Margao       Kalva          7846789840|
|3    Harry    Valpoi       Arvalam        8945670024|
|4    Tina     Ponda        Bondla         9811109876|
```

```
 Df2

|Mobile_No     Mobile_Company|
|----------------------------|
|7896095431    Samsung       |
|9456789034    Redmi         |
|6789065486    iphone        |
|7846789840    oppo          |
|8945670024    vivo          |
|9875692341    Oneplus       |
|9811109876    HTC           |
```

What i want to do is to append Mobile_Company to dataframe one with matching column values of Mobile_No in df1 with Mobile_No in df2.

Comment: Use `Df1.merge(Df2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use [`df1.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
joined_df = Df1.merge(Df2, how='inner', on='Mobile_No')
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
pd.merge(Df1, Df2, how=’inner’, on='Mobile_No')
```